# How can i get multiple string in between multiple different characters?

Tags: c++, c++11

i have searched up several of your topics, but i can't seem to figure out how to get between multiple different characters.

Example

```
string str = "AG/B/C,BC/D,AD,AE/R/B/A,AB";
```

i want to extract between two /  or two , only
final result should be:

```
B,AD,R,B,AB

string temp;
for(int i=0; i < str.size(); i++)     
    {
        temp += str[i];                  
        if((str[i] == '/') || str[i] == ',')                   
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: regex may work. or you can iterate over it. What have you tried?

Comment: i have tried the size_t start = find('/')  and size_t end = find('/', start)

Comment: doesn't search for comma tho

Comment: You'll have to be more precise, because I have no idea how your requirement matches your example.  The characters between `/` and `,` are `C` and the first `D`.

Comment: between / as in  /   B  /    between 2 slash or 2 comma like , AD,

Comment: An easy solution will be iterate over the string, when you meet letter, move on, when you meet `/` or `,`, check if the last special symbol is match, take the sub-string, if not, change the indicator for the last match, move on

Comment: @user58504 -- *i have searched up several of your topics* -- This is not a matter of searching for several topics.  You just need to write a loop scanning each character, and determining what to do when you encounter that character, as Danh suggested.

Comment: i edited and add something that iterator thought the character, would that be a good start?

Comment: This is exactly what regex's are designed to do.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: You can use stack. Go on pushing characters other than `'/' and ','`. When a `'/' or ','` is encountered then go on popping till stack becomes empty of a matching `'/' or ','` is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string temp = "";
char flag = ' ';
int cursor = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
{
        if(str[i] == '/' || str[i] == ',')
        {
                if(flag == str[i] && cursor < i-1)
                        temp+=str.substr(cursor+1,i-cursor-1)+",";
                flag = str[i];
                cursor = i;
        }
}
```

Comment: i realize that this one works until the very end let say AB/A, AB    it doesn't grab the AB since there no comma at the end, so i was wonder if u can explain what cursor for , so t hat i can try to make a else statement with it

Comment: Cursor is a position of the last occurrence of '/' or ','.  So, if you want to grab the last AB, you should add 

temp+=str.substr(cursor+1,str.size()-cursor-2)+",";

after **for** loop (I'm not sure about -2, it should be checked)

Comment: So, when a for loop ends, cursor will contain the position of the last "," in case of your string and you should add to temp everything starting from that position to the end of the string

Comment: and then after that if statement i added if temp.back() == ','  ....temp.pop_back() so it removes the last comma

Answer (score 0):

It is a complex use case because you want delimiters to act in pairs. Certainly it is possible to use regexes for that, but IMHO it will not be simpler to either read of write than direct processing. Simply you must store the last separator.

```
string str = "AG/B/C,BC/D,AD,AE/R/B/A";
char last = '\0';   // initialize last separator to an impossible value
string temp;
for(size_t i=0; i < str.size(); i++)     
{
    if((str[i] == '/') || str[i] == ',')  // found a separator                 
    {
        if (last == str[i]) {     // is it the second on a pair
            std::cout << temp << std::endl; // or store temp in a vector for later use...
        }
        last = str[i];     // store last separator for future use
        temp.clear();      // reset the temp string
    }
    else temp.push_back(str[i]);  // non separator chars are added to temp string
}
```